# Understanding php namespace and why the fatal error: undefined constant

Tags: php, namespaces

Trying to understand how namespace in php works and am stuck.

This below is the architecture of the project.

[image]

Class: **Loader.php** (suppose to load controller/model/ library but for now gibberish test codes)

```
namespace system\core;

class Loader
{
    public function index()
    {
        echo 'loader';
    }

    public function controller($pathtocontroller)
    {
        // Echo path to the controller
        echo $pathtocontroller;

    }
}
```

**index.php**

```
require 'system/core/Loader.php';
require 'system/core/BaseController.php';
require 'app/controller/common/HomeController.php';

use system\core;
use app\controller;

$loader = new \system\core\Loader();
$loader->controller(app\controller\common\HomeController);
```

and this is the error I get

> Fatal error: Undefined constant 'app\controller\common\HomeController'
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\psrstd\index.php on line 20. Lin 20 on index is $loader->controller(app\controller\common\HomeController);

**Expected Result:** app/controller/common/HomeController

in case you wondering what's in there at the HomeController (again gibberish test code)

```
namespace app\controller\common;
use system\core\BaseController;

class HomeController extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        echo 'home';
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you tring to achieve?

Comment: @u_mulder, the HomeController is at app/controller/common. I was simply trying to echo the path to the controller.

Comment: Why do you need path to the controller?

Comment: @u_mulder, load the controller like so $this->load->controller('common/HomeController'); ..

Comment: @u_mulder, but that is later ... Loader.php is supposed to be a class loader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are passing a constant type to your controller method,

you are aiming to pass an object [ `dependency injection` ] so you will need to instantiate your argument like :

```
$loader->controller(new \app\controller\common\HomeController);
```

otherwise you may send this argument as a string like :

```
$loader->controller("\\app\\controller\\common\\HomeController");
```

and instantiate that object within your method [ `as a factory method` ]

```
public function controller($pathtocontroller)
{
    // new $pathtocontroller and so on

}
```

Further reading :

[What is Dependency Injection?](http://fabien.potencier.org/what-is-dependency-injection.html)

[Factory design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)

Comment: this worked $loader->controller("\\app\\controller\\common\\HomeController");", but looks ugly. Is there a better way?

Comment: what do you mean by looks ugly?

Comment: \\app\\controller\\common\\HomeControll‌​er .. do I need to '\\' ? My old project I use to do $this->load->controller(common/HomeController) now having to do this $this->load->controller(common\\HomeController) would look ugly ... I'll do it if there is no other way but generally asking ... can it be done any better?.

Comment: the backslash is the former separator for namespaces in PHP, you can not git rid of it, and since the backslash is also the escaping character so you must escape it like this `\\`